# VBA to autofilter in a specific column for each criteria and copy the result to a new sheet

Tags: vba, autofilter

Could you please help in automating the below task through VBA.

Need to filter on each region (Column F) and copy the result to a new worksheet. would be helpful if this can be done through looping as the original data set contains more regions. Thanks for the help

Column F (First 10 cells): East west west North South East South South West North

Comment: You can attach a screenshot, but I don't think anyone would be willing to help without more details and what you have tried so far. You can Record Macro and check the generated code.

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you

```
Sub filter_copy()
    Dim strfilterrng As String
    Dim col As Long
    Dim mainsheet As String
    mainsheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    col = 6
    strfilterrng = find_filter_range()
    lc = get_last_row_in_column(col)
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range(strfilterrng)
    x = r.Columns.Count()
    arr = GetUnique(ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(r.Cells.Item(1).Row + 1, col).Address & ":" & ActiveSheet.Cells(lc, col).Address))
    For Index = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    ActiveSheet.Range(strfilterrng).AutoFilter Field:=col - x, Criteria1:=arr(Index)
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets(mainsheet).Select
    Next Index
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub

Function find_filter_range() As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    If sh.AutoFilterMode = True Then
        find_filter_range = sh.AutoFilter.Range.Address
    Else
        sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter
        find_filter_range = sh.AutoFilter.Range.Address
    End If
End Function

Function get_last_row_in_column(ByVal columnnum As Long) As Long
    get_last_row_in_column = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, columnnum).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

Function GetUnique(ByRef rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim d As Object, k, tmp As String, i As Long, arr() As Variant
    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In rng
        tmp = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(tmp) > 0 Then d(tmp) = d(tmp) + 1
    Next c

    i = 0
    For Each k In d.keys
        ReDim Preserve arr(0 To i)
        arr(i) = k
        i = i + 1
    Next k
    GetUnique = arr
End Function
```

Comment: You should run the filter_copy sub routine with the data sheet as the active sheet

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. however the code is interrupted with error 1004 (auto filter method of Range class failed). Please note that i have data from E2:F12, E2, F2 being headings (Company, Region)

Comment: Is that the only data you have on the sheet?
E2:F12

Comment: My actual office data consists of 79456 Rows and 12 columns. However for simulation purpose i have created data in two columns (E and F)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B02dDRY-jgk8Yks0bG5nbDlvME0/view. Please find the downloadable xls file. Thanks again for your help